# JSON не работает под IE 11

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer

Доброго времени суток. Нужна ваша помощь в моей проблеме. Пишу веб приложение. При запуске на локальной машине все отрабатывает в IE нормально(если можно так сказать про ie). При размещении и запуске на сервере, веб сайт грузится но перестает **"JSON" не определено** при выполнении JSON.stringify.. Подскажите, может кто сталкивался, буду признателен.

Comment: Точно идет попытка открытия в IE11? Возможно у него устанавливается режим совместимости поумолчанию

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо) так и есть, проблема в совместимости была, убрал галочку в настройках совместимости ie. Только не понятно почему она стоит по умолчанию..

Comment: Открыть devtools по F12 и в нем справа сверху можно увидеть что выставлено.